# Loss of power when park lights switched on

Tags: nissan, wiring

My Nissan Nv200  2012  right hand drive has this issue when ever i am driving then switch on the park light so as to illuminate the dashboard i immediately lose pedal power.Switch it off and vehicle picks up rev immediately again switch lights on again Throttle position drops and holds at 21% rev just up to 3000rpm no more.  Scratch my head auto electrician can't seem to figure it out at all help?

Comment: Has anyone fitted aftermarket stuff? If so, rip it out and start from standard...

Comment: No not that i know of altho vehicle was bought used it worked fine for over a year have it Sep 2017 to now Sep 2019

Comment: Whenever weird stuff starts happening with dash lights, I would (1) replace the rear brake light bulbs. I believe they are inexpensive 1157's. If that did not fix it, then (2) suspect the alternator. Alternators do weird things when they start breaking down. I've seen other bizarre problems on rare occasion, but by far the two listed are the most prevalent. If you want to chase a rare problem you need to get your multi-meter out and start measuring voltage drops across sensors.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you car has a throttle pedal sensor.

My guess would be that you have a bad earth connection somewhere, so that the sensor is having to find its earth through the lighting circuit.

I would check the resistance of the ground connection at the throttle pedal as a start.

Comment: Yes i thought of that .so i was thinking is it one of those relays that has a normal open normal close interchange relay that ive been trying to find it i can hear a relay inside a fuse and relay box with what looks like a module please i could get help locating this relay circuit diagram and for the pedal sensor Nissan Nv200 Vanette 2012 hr16 engine thanks

Comment: Tried exchanging it with another vehicle that works  pedal sensor same thing

Comment: I didn’t suggest that it was a faulty pedal, I suggested that the earth to it may be faulty.  You need to check the power/earth feed.

Comment: If you have access to another vehicle, then you could compare the voltages on each of the throttle sensor connections.